# How to target the text in nav ul li

Tags: html, css

So I have

```
<nav>
  <ul> 
    <li>
      <a>
      <img src = "">
      This Text is what I want to grab
      </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I want to grab the text up above and be able to change the y positioning of it. Anybody have an idea? Currently it looks like the **img** and the **text** are right next to each other. I want the text exactly below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

just add

```
ul li a img{display:block;}
```

and that's it